# Nagios Core - Automation

Tags: nagios, automation, network-monitoring

We are using Nagios Core for monitoring devices and we are currently facing some hurdles with monitoring a large scale environment. It requires a lot of manual tasks such as collecting OID's and MIB's, host details and services addition.

Is there any automated task for scanning the network, fetching host info and selecting the services that need to monitored? Please suggest a few alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

- Large Scale means what in your case? 10? 100? 1000? 10000? 100000?
- What type of equipment do you want to monitor? Workstations? Office PCs? Servers? Routers? Switches? Industial controllers?

You didn't tell us the most basic information, so I would like to downvote your question, but I can't - Lucky You ;-)

In spite of missing information, some simple ideas:

- You could use the data contained in you ansible / cfengine / puppet / whatever-centralized-admin-system-you-use to find out the services you have configured, then creating your Nagios configuration via (Power-)Shell / Java / Perl / whatever your preferred scripting / programming language is.
- If you have scriptable access to your machines, like ssh with public key authentication, you can collect a lot of information like this from any admin machine: `for host in $(cat list-of-hosts-file); do ssh $host 'df; ps -ax; netstat -an; ... some more commands to get information you need ...'; done >your-results-file.txt`
- You could do a simple network scan using any professional tool, any more cheapish tool or even just `netcat -z` for just getting open ports information.
- If this large scale thing is a Microsoft-ish environment, you at least have some domain controllers which know a lot about your machines. Just use the information they have available for you.
- Of course SNMP might give some insight. The little program `snmpwalk` might help you to collect all the data available via SNMP

TomTomTom

Comment: Thanks for your information, adding some more precised information to the questions currently we are having 200-300 networks devices that includes switches, routers, telephony devices, firewalls of cisco, juniper, alcatel, fortiner. Its not a Microsoft environment there are all on a private LAN network with SNMP enabled. Also we dont have scriptable access to these devices.

Comment: Ok, that's a bit more information. Some hundred machines, many different kinds, SNMP agents everywhere. First make a list of what you want to monitor. Then use SNMP to get information about your machines, maybe in a loop like mentioned above. Try `snmpwalk -c public -v 1 1.2.3.4`, of course using a valid IP of your network or a valid name instead, also valid credential instead of "public" and maybe another version instead of 1. Later you'll have to filter the data received and, together with the information what you want to monitor - turn it into Nagios configuration files.